# When should wall off my Terran base and when should I not?

Tags: starcraft-2

When playing with Terran in ranked in any mode (1v1 or 3v3). I learned that against Zerg the base should be always closed. I do the same against Protoss or Terran, but I was told by some players that against Protoss or Terran, the base should not be walled off.

So in which cases should the Terran base be walled off?

Comment: You close the base off in case of zergling harass since they are fast and can cause havoc at your mineral line. You should be able to properly defend by the time a slow zealot or marine comes knocking on your door.

Comment: There's never really a reason not to wall off unless you're doing an incredibly tight build order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Walling](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Walling) is very popular as Terran and clearly makes defending zergling and zealot rushes significantly easier.  It can also be helpful against Terran matchups to help prevent scouting and to delay an army pushing up into your base (where you might have siege tanks etc... set up)

It does however have some disadvantages, specifically

> Enemy units that have equal or greater range than your own units can safely attack the wall itself, while your own units cannot attack back from behind the wall.
>
> If your wall of Supply Depots is breached, you can become supply blocked, rendering you unable to reinforce or produce more units during the attack.

Although your wall can be very useful at defending against some attacks, in other situations it can also be fairly vulnerable until you are in a position where you can push out past the wall with your main army.

I have seen some high-level players in matches where they didn't wall off (even against Zerg) My understanding is that its possible to hold off early zergling etc... pushes with good building placement around your CC instead of a wall-off, however this seems very micro-intensive - I'm sure that anyone other than pro-level players would be much better off just relying on a wall-in and focussing their attention on more important things.

My advice would be to just wall off every time, **especially** against Zerg. Although it can be a disadvantage in some situations, its a very minor disadvantage when compared to the advantage it gives in other situations (e.g. Zergling rush).

Comment: also in a tournament you get to know your opponent and predict whether he'll do a early zerg rush, letting you win those few seconds of SCV travel time

Comment: When the Terran do not wall the main, its often due to a 1-Rax  FE. I my self never wall the main versus a Zerg when I 1-Rax FE. I bunker the NE and have a constant production of Supplies, and atleast 1 tank ASAP.

Comment: @AtlasEU When I 1-Rax FE I build my supply depot and Rax as a partial wall - that way if I see a zergling rush coming I only need to place down 1 more supply depot to finish the wall.  Its not as good as a full wall, but its better than nothing.

Comment: @Justin Its viable indeed. Only problem is, that if you get caught off guard and dont have the 100 minerals in reserve. The good thing about it though, is that you can "clump" up SCVs in the gap and have marines shooting at the lings. And if he got speedlings, ALWAYS expect a banebust follow up :)

Answer (score 4):

AS terran player, I ALWAYS wall my base.
This helps you a lot (as mates told before). You can protect from fast rushes of every race, using 2 depos, and 1 barrack. Behind the barrack you put 1 bunker. This gives you a early defense from attacks and scouts.

Obviously if you have scouted, you can see if your opponent is going to rush you or not, so you can wall only with the depos and rax.

But once you have expand for first time, you can wall your exapand to protect better your base.

## Edit

Vs Protoss you have to take a lot of care than before, because now they have the new unit called  [Oracle](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Oracle). This unit can kill 1 vce for every 1 second... So just think.. you take away your vce when have passed 4 seconds.. these means, 4 vce's less!!!! Imagin when they send you 2 oracles... I recommend a lot to put 1 or 2 torrets behind minerals... These can help you to bring rines to mineral lines ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Why you should wall off versus Zerg:**

- To avoid zerglings running into your main base (rush / pokes)
- To deny scouting

**Why you shouldent wall off versus Zerg:**

- Always wall off versus a Zerg!

**Why you should wall off versus Protoss:**

- To avoid Zealots and stalkers from entering your base during early
  game (rush / pokes)
- To avoid in-base Canon-rush
- To deny scouting

**Why you shouldent wall off versus Protoss:**

- You can execute your builds faster
- With minor micro, you can easily deny a Protoss rush /poke /
  canon-rush

**Why you should wall off versus Terran:**

- To deny rushes / pokes such as MM (Marine Maruder)
- To deny Hellions rushing into your mainbase
- To deny scouting

**Why you shouldent wall off versus Terran:**

- You can execute your builds faster

In general I always close with 3 supplydepots or 2 and a bunker versus Terran and Protoss.
And I close off versus Zerg with 2 supplydepots and 1 rax.

Your wall should reflect what you scout versus Terran and Protoss.
(VS. Zerg always wall-off)

Comment: For Protoss, I would also add, to keep DT's from sneaking into your main's mineral line.

Answer (score -1):

Pre-expo, there's no reason to have your base open - there's just nothing that needs to go out, and what little traffic there is (the scout and the worker sent to make an expo) can be handled manually - there isn't much else that needs your attention span anyway.

Post-expo, there's no reason to close your base - any attacks will hit your expansion first, and your army should be sitting at or near the secondary base, ready to respond to attacks (as opposed to hiding behind a supply depot). If your army is in your main base, having it closed will only lead to a slower response in case of attack; if it is in the secondary base, your rally points will be screwed up for no good reason.

Closing only makes sense if there's nothing outside of the base to protect - and if this is the case, there's also little traffic to the outside, so manually opening isn't too much trouble.

Comment: 1. By not walling, you can execute your build faster! 2. Attacking the main will happen as often as attacks on the NE, so saying that attacks always hits the expo is wrong! 3. Closing / walling the main or NE always comes down to what your opponant is doing - which is one of the points you scout in the first place.

Comment: @AtlasEU on most maps, the expo is in the way. Hence, most attacks hit the expo first. For the rest, you should be watching the rocks anyway - general base defense was not the purpose of this post, so I didn't talk about it. I haven't played in a while, but could you tell me what type of frequent attack hits the main before the expo? I can only think of cheesy one-two unit rushes, which are countered by scouting, not army positioning anyway.
For the faster build thing, I disagree. There are very few builds that require it, and you need to be pro level to use it for all games. Too niche.

Comment: A lot of attacks are focused on the the main to draw attention off the NE or 3rd - or vise versa. Going directly into the NE is often just bad. Regarding scouting - a quick lesson; You are not supposed to lose your scouting unit, it should retur to scout for timings and FEs aswell - so its not just for a gas check etc. Regarding execusion of builds - it can change the early game for as low as Platinum plays. And its good for defending reaper rushes.